# P2TR Scriptpath failing (Timelocked contract)

Tags: taproot, locktime, contracts, p2tr

Goal is to archive the following logic:

```
$alice = A;
$bob = B;

pk($bob) || (pk($alice) && older(10))
```

I went through [The Taproot Workshop](https://github.com/bitcoinops/taproot-workshop/) and came up with the following code:

```
from io import BytesIO
import random
import util
from test_framework.key import generate_key_pair, generate_bip340_key_pair, generate_schnorr_nonce, ECKey, ECPubKey, SECP256K1_FIELD_SIZE, SECP256K1, SECP256K1_ORDER
from test_framework.musig import aggregate_musig_signatures, aggregate_schnorr_nonces, generate_musig_key, musig_digest, sign_musig
from test_framework.script import TapLeaf, TapTree, TaprootSignatureHash, SIGHASH_ALL_TAPROOT
from test_framework.address import program_to_witness
from test_framework.messages import CTransaction, COutPoint, CTxIn, CTxOut, CTxInWitness
from test_framework.util import assert_equal




my_privkey, my_pubkey = generate_bip340_key_pair()
delay_privkey, delay_pubkey = generate_bip340_key_pair()


tapscript_res = TapLeaf().construct_pk_delay(delay_pubkey, 10)
taptree = TapTree(key=my_pubkey)
taptree.huffman_constructor([(1, tapscript_res)])

taproot_script, tweak, control_map = taptree.construct()
taproot_pubkey = my_pubkey.tweak_add(tweak) 
program = taproot_pubkey.get_bytes()
address = program_to_witness(1, program)
print("Segwit Address:", address)


test = util.TestWrapper()
test.setup()
node = test.nodes[0]

tx = node.generate_and_send_coins(address)
node.generate(2)
print("Transaction {}, output 0\nsent to {}\n".format(tx.hash, address))
spending_tx = test.create_spending_transaction(tx.hash, version=2)

print("Spending transaction:\n{}".format(spending_tx))
sighashA = TaprootSignatureHash(spending_tx,
                               [tx.vout[0]],
                               SIGHASH_ALL_TAPROOT,
                               input_index=0,
                               scriptpath=True,
                               script=tapscript_res.script)

signatureA = delay_privkey.sign_schnorr(sighashA)

print("Signature for TapLeafA: {}\n".format(signatureA.hex()))
witness_elements = [signatureA, tapscript_res.script, control_map[tapscript_res.script]]
spending_tx.wit.vtxinwit.append(CTxInWitness(witness_elements))

# Test mempool acceptance
assert not node.test_transaction(spending_tx)
node.generate(21)
assert node.test_transaction(spending_tx)
print("Success!")
test.shutdown()
```

I tried numerous changes to the spending process, however the output I get is always:

```
Segwit Address: bcrt1p0jh5l700aqtnxtn97vhf3vqf6w700dzj5h9vahx5aqhrklu8glgqtwgnn0

Client version is /Satoshi:22.99.0(testnode0)/

Balance: 50.00000000

Transaction 78f7017342f86f03af0e27e127ce7578311f967b950f1dc65b9b928653766117, output 0
sent to bcrt1p0jh5l700aqtnxtn97vhf3vqf6w700dzj5h9vahx5aqhrklu8glgqtwgnn0

Spending transaction:
CTransaction(nVersion=2 vin=[CTxIn(prevout=COutPoint(hash=78f7017342f86f03af0e27e127ce7578311f967b950f1dc65b9b928653766117 n=0) scriptSig= nSequence=0)] vout=[CTxOut(nValue=0.50000000 scriptPubKey=001415d2012d191dbad6cf7881b1cad4af4bb72b6a57)] wit=CTxWitness() nLockTime=0)
Signature for TapLeafA: bbad433804dcdc1070894abe58e52fe38ebc87c9b337187aee0d77ca0299e78f6f212131f6bd19dbc3d7655304322b43b99ecadb64c84d3f9fcceebcc25184c6

{'txid': 'b462759670cbca3c6449fa18f0a0a45044317dadd13a58521549fc1e42219c6f', 'wtxid': '17e532c0447fe3cf6ef52b6e23f69d744e745ba7c6ccd5d53689fe3da968aa18', 'allowed': False, 'reject-reason': 'non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Data push larger than necessary)'}
{'txid': 'b462759670cbca3c6449fa18f0a0a45044317dadd13a58521549fc1e42219c6f', 'wtxid': '17e532c0447fe3cf6ef52b6e23f69d744e745ba7c6ccd5d53689fe3da968aa18', 'allowed': False, 'reject-reason': 'non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Data push larger than necessary)'}
```

Depending on how I change the code, the `reject-reason` varies.

Any ideas what is faulty in my code?

If there is an existing way to approach this using other languages/libraries, I am happy for hints.